# How to make Scrollbar track shorter

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor-server-side

[image]

[image]

This is my first time using a scrollbar. I have a scrollbar and I want the track - indicated with yellow - to be shorter. Right now on my page it looks silly as the scrollbar goes further then the page itself as the page has curved edges - it sticks out. I want the bar to be cut off a tad on top and bottom and then be centred on this edge of the page. So far I have:

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px; /* for vertical scrollbar */
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

    /* Handle on hover */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: #666;
    }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: yellow;
    height:40px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: just give the track the same radius as the handle or make the track transparent?

Comment: The handle? You mean give the scrollbar-track a border-radius: 10px?

Comment: Making it transparent doesn't solve the corner issue.. it just hides the yellow which I have used to show the problem

Comment: probably misunderstood what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    
}
```

This worked